# Linq to Sql Search through Tags

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Ok so I have these tables:

**Video**

- Id
- Title

**VideoTag**

- Id
- VideoId
- TagId

**Tag**

- Id
- Name

I need a LINQ to SQL query to perform a **search** on the Videos, **either by the title or by the tags**.

For the moment all I have is this for searching by the title:

```
IQueryable<Video> videos =
    from v in ctx.Videos
    where v.Title.Contains(SearchString)
    select
    new Video
    {
        Id = v.Id,
        Title = v.Title
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from v in ctx.Videos
join vt in ctx.VideoTags on v.Id equals vt.VideoId
join t in ctx.Tag on vt.TagId equals t.Id
where v.Title.Contains(SearchString) || t.Name.Contains(SearchString)
select
    new Video
    {
        Id = v.Id,
        Title = v.Title
    };
```

Comment: 'twas so obvious :) Thanks!